# Is there a way to change the thumbnail of an app in the android task switcher (long press on home button)

Tags: android, thumbnails

is there a way to hide / mask the thumbnail of an activity proposed in the task switcher ?
By task switcher, I mean the menu that displays active applications with a long press on the home button.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override [Activity.onCreateThumbnail()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas%29) to do this.

Comment: This is not working on many devices. See this thread: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370

Comment: i have seen on other threads..people are saying this solution doesnt work now

Comment: The callback is actually _never invoked_ in most Android versions, as can be seen in the source code

Comment: From Activity documentation: "This method was deprecated in API level 28. Method doesn't do anything and will be removed in the future."