# Can I control the screenshot that is shown in Android's task switcher?

Tags: android, privacy

My add displays private data, so I don't want it to be possible to see the app contents in the task switcher.

Comment: A quick guess,  The task switcher only shows background tasks.  Could you change the UI in onPause(), I guess before the super call, and restore it in onResume()?

Comment: Very similar question with a different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848132/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-thumbnail-of-an-app-in-the-android-task-switcher-l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't control what it shows, but you *can* exclude it from appearing in Recent Apps altogether. In your manifest, add the following attribute to any `activity` tags for Activities that should not show in Recent Apps:

`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

See also: [`<activity>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Or, if you want to be in the recent tasks list, but simply do not want to have your app's thumbnail retained, use `FLAG_SECURE`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Interesting, I didn't know that would prevent the system from displaying it. What displays in place of it?

Comment: It works! The screenshot in the recent tasks list is all black. (That was meant to be @CommonsWare not Aha by the way!)

Comment: Yes, as @Timmmm notes, screenshots (whether recent tasks or the manual stuff you do on ICS+ devices) come out blank for "secure" windows. It's conceivable that all-black might get replaced by some other stock image in the future (e.g., bugdroid in police riot gear), but it should never be your app's screen contents.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have researched a lot but could not find how the Overview(or recent tasks) behave in Android 5.0 onwards. Can you tell me how recent task image is displayed now when FLAG_SECURE is set ?